# Expand specific rows in Angular-ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using angular-ui-grid 3.0.5 with the treeview extension to display a tree. The data loads normally, everything works as expected, except that `expandRow` fails silently.

My use case is this: suppose we have a path like a > b > c and I need c shown to the user as preselected. I know the selection is correctly done because when I manually expand the parent rows, the child row is indeed selected.

Should I call `expandAllRows`, all rows would be expanded. However, calling `expandRow` with references on rows a and b taken from `gridOptions.data` leads to nothing happening: all rows will remain collapsed.

Is there any precaution to be taken that I have maybe overlooked, or is this a bug?

There's [one mention](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3841#issuecomment-152575219) in a closed issue that may be related to this but problem I'm having, but I'm not even sure it's related, given how dry the comment/solution was.

There's no example of using `expandRow` in the documentation but it's in both the API and the source code.

Answer (score 0):

The `gridRow` objects mentioned in the documentation http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.treeBase.api:PublicApi are not the elements you put into the data array (though this seems to be not explained anywhere).

What the function expects is an object that the grid creates when building the tree, you can access them by looping through the grids `treeBase.tree` array. This will only be valid when the grid has built the tree, it seems, so it is not directly available when filling in the data, that's why registering a DataChangeCallback helps here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3051

```
// expand the top-level rows
// https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3051
ctrl.gridApi.grid.registerDataChangeCallback(function() {
  if (ctrl.gridApi.grid.treeBase.tree instanceof Array) {
    angular.forEach(ctrl.gridApi.grid.treeBase.tree, function(node) {
      if (node.row.treeLevel == 0) {
        ctrl.gridApi.treeBase.expandRow(node.row);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  self.onContentReady = function (e) {
        e.component.expandRow(e.component.getKeyByRowIndex(0));
        e.component.expandRow(e.component.getKeyByRowIndex(1));
    };
```

selec which row you wanna expand